# Writing a synopsis in LaTeX (comparing text columns)

Tags: multicol

I want to recreate this text here:
[image: Synopsis]

I tried the mulitcol package, but either it can't span over more than one page or I'm not able to use it correctly. After some googeling, I haven't found a package, which does the job. Is there any package, that can do this?

I know, that there are some things still missing in the layout like the lettrine package, but for now, it is mainly about the columns.

For now, I recreated it like this (MWE):

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{Liederheft}
\usepackage[ngerman,latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength{\restlength}
\newcommand{\versebox}[2]{%
\setlength{\restlength}{\linewidth}%
\advance\restlength by -2em\relax%
\makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}#1\hfill}%
\parbox[t]{\restlength}{#2}%
\medskip%
}

\newcommand{\verseresponsebox}[2]{%
\setlength{\restlength}{\linewidth}%
\advance\restlength by -2em\relax%
\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{
\makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}V\hfill}%
\parbox[t]{\restlength}{#1}%
\medskip%

\makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}R\hfill}%
\parbox[t]{\restlength}{#2}%
}%
\bigskip%

}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Alle knien}
\noindent\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}%
\begin{multicols}{2}%
\verseresponsebox{CROSS Adjutórium nostrum in nómine Domini.}{Qui fécit cáelum et térram.}%
\verseresponsebox{Dómine, exáudi oratiónem meam.}{Et clámor meus ad te véniat.}
\verseresponsebox{Dóminus vobíscum.}{Et cum spíritu tuo.\\}

\verseresponsebox{CROSS Unsere Hilfe ist im Namen des Herrn.}{Der Himmel und Erde erschaffen hat.}
\verseresponsebox{Unsere Hilfe ist im Namen des Herrn.}{Der Himmel und Erde erschaffen hat.}
\verseresponsebox{Der Herr sei mit euch.}{Und mit deinem Geiste.}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\ \begin{center}
Oremus
\end{center}

Actiónes nostras, quáe\-sumus, Dómine, aspi\-rándo práeveni et adjuván\-do proséquere: ut cuncta nostra orátio et operátio a
te semper incípiat, et per te
coepta finiátur. Per Chris-
tum, Dóminum nostrum.\\\ \\\ \\
\makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}R\hfill}Amen.

\ \begin{center}
Lasset uns beten.
\end{center}

Wir bitten Dich, o
Herr, komm unse-
rem Handeln durch Deine
Eingebung zuvor und be-
gleite es mit Deiner Hilfe:
auf dass all unser Beten
und Tun stets von Dir sei-
nen Anfang nehme und
durch vollendet werde.
Durch Christus, unsern
Herrn.\\ 
\makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}R\hfill}Amen.
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a table do the same job? (Preparing sth.)

Comment: @MS-SPO I thought also about longtable or something like this, but the problem is, that it can't break cells. I can not have a pagebreak inside a cell, which would be essential here.

Comment: Yeah, just ran into the same problem. One more question: do you want 2 pages on 1 sheet, landscape? If so, why isn't using ordinary sheet layout AND printing 2 pages per sheet during printing (paper, pdf, ...) an option?

Comment: The `paracol` package may come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `paracol` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman,latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newcommand{\verseresponsebox}[4]{%
  \selectlanguage{latin}
  \makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}{V}\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{#1}
  \medskip%
\switchcolumn
  \selectlanguage{ngerman}
  \makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}{V}\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{#2}%
  \medskip%
\switchcolumn*
  \selectlanguage{latin}
  \makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}{R}\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{#3}%
  \bigskip%
\switchcolumn
  \selectlanguage{ngerman}
  \makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}{R}\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{#4}%
  \bigskip%
\switchcolumn*
}%

\newcommand{\cross}{\textcolor{red}{\ding{64}}\enspace}
\newcommand{\mylettrine}[2]{\lettrine{\normalfont\textcolor{red}{#1}}{\normalfont #2}}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Alle knien}\bigskip

\begin{paracol}{2}%
\verseresponsebox{\cross Adjutórium nostrum in nómine Domini.}
                 {\cross Unsere Hilfe ist im Namen des Herrn.} 
                 {Qui fécit cáelum et térram.}
                 {Der Himmel und Erde erschaffen hat.}%
                 
\verseresponsebox{Dómine, exáudi oratiónem meam.}
                 {Unsere Hilfe ist im Namen des Herrn.}
                 {Et clámor meus ad te véniat.}
                 {Der Himmel und Erde erschaffen hat.}
                 
\verseresponsebox{Dóminus vobíscum.}
                 {Der Herr sei mit euch.}
                 {Et cum spíritu tuo.}
                 {Und mit deinem Geiste.}
                 
  \begin{center}
    Oremus
  \end{center}
\switchcolumn
  \begin{center}
     Lasset uns beten.
  \end{center}
\switchcolumn*

  \mylettrine{A}{ctiónes} nostras, quáe\-sumus, Dómine, aspi\-rándo 
    práeveni et adjuván\-do proséquere: ut cuncta nostra orátio et 
    operátio a te semper incípiat, et per te coepta finiátur. Per 
    Christum, Dóminum nostrum.
\switchcolumn
  \mylettrine{W}{ir} bitten Dich, o Herr, komm unserem Handeln 
    durch Deine Eingebung zuvor und begleite es mit Deiner Hilfe: 
    auf dass all unser Beten und Tun stets von Dir seinen Anfang 
    nehme und durch vollendet werde. Durch Christus, unsern Herrn.
\switchcolumn*

  \makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}{R}\hfill}Amen.
\switchcolumn 
  \makebox[2em]{\textcolor{red}{R}\hfill}Amen.
\end{paracol}
\bigskip

\textcolor{red}{some text that spans both columns some text that spans both columns some text that spans both columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly, what I need and didn't find.